# Detect if user is scrolling

Tags: javascript

How can I detect in javascript if the user is scrolling?

Comment: No, I want from another function to write `if(scolling)`. Is `if(window.onscroll)` the same ?

Comment: You can set `scrolling` in the `onscroll`.  (p.s.: no, that's not the same)

Comment: Can you add more detail to the question?

Comment: The user never 'is scrolling'. There is only a scroll action, not a scroll state.

Comment: I tryed to set `scrolling` in the `onscroll` but `scrolling` will always be `true`. When do I remake it `false`?

Comment: @user1365010: D'OH!  I didn't think of that.  What exactly are you trying to do?  Why do you need to know if the user is scrolling?

Comment: Because I want to stop the scroll of the user if he pass on a certain `div` then after 2 seconds reboot the scroll. But if I write `onmousemove="stopscroll();"`, I must not reboot the scroll if he wasn't scrolling.

Comment: Interesting. I have never 'rebooted' a scroll. Care to elaborate?

Comment: I mean to make a setInterval that emulate a normal scroll.

Comment: @user1365010 it sounds like you're trying to rewrite something that's already been done many times before: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+animate+scroll

Comment: See [Javascript - Detecting scroll direction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223341/javascript-detecting-scroll-direction)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

this works:

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {  
// called when the window is scrolled.  
}
```

*edit:*

you said this is a function in a TimeInterval..
Try doing it like so:

```
userHasScrolled = false;
window.onscroll = function (e)
{
    userHasScrolled = true;
}
```

then inside your Interval insert this:

```
if(userHasScrolled)
{
//do your code here
userHasScrolled = false;
}
```

Comment: But it's a function in a setInterval!

Comment: @user1365010: What is?  What are you talking about?  You need to add more detail to the question.

Comment: @user1365010 this answer is (at its core) the best you can do.

Comment: #FYI, its seems not woking when the container was scrolling, body.scroll() works, so I added both,

Comment: This only detects if scrolling has occurred, not whether the user cause that scrolling to occur, so would also trigger if other js caused scrolling to occur.

Comment: I agree this is not a good answer as this only detect if scrolling occured but not if the USER has scrolled

Answer (score 13):

You just said javascript in your tags, so @Wampie Driessen post could helps you.

I want also to contribute, so you can use the following when using jQuery if you need it.

```
 //Firefox
 $('#elem').bind('DOMMouseScroll', function(e){
     if(e.detail > 0) {
         //scroll down
         console.log('Down');
     }else {
         //scroll up
         console.log('Up');
     }

     //prevent page fom scrolling
     return false;
 });

 //IE, Opera, Safari
 $('#elem').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
     if(e.wheelDelta< 0) {
         //scroll down
         console.log('Down');
     }else {
         //scroll up
         console.log('Up');
     }

     //prevent page fom scrolling
     return false;
 });
```

Another example:

```
$(function(){
    var _top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var _direction;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var _cur_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(_top < _cur_top)
        {
            _direction = 'down';
        }
        else
        {
            _direction = 'up';
        }
        _top = _cur_top;
        console.log(_direction);
    });
});​
```

Comment: Isn't jQuery supposed to abstract out browser differences?  Why do you have methods for different browsers?  Is `$('#elem').bind('scroll'` not good enough?  EDIT: Never mind, I saw your 2nd example.

Comment: nothing wrong with a little native javascript every now and then.

Comment: Don't you mean `e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || e.originalEvent.detail` ?

Comment: **WARNING:** The wheel events in this answer are nonstandard and deprecated. Use the `wheel` event.

Comment: I haven't tested this but according to MDN DOMMouseScroll isn't supported in most browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMMouseScroll

Answer (score 11):

```
window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
    window.lastScrollTime = new Date().getTime()
});
function is_scrolling() {
    return window.lastScrollTime && new Date().getTime() < window.lastScrollTime + 500
}
```

Change the 500 to the number of milliseconds after the last scroll event at which you consider the user to be "no longer scrolling".

(`addEventListener` is better than `onScroll` because the former can coexist nicely with any other code that uses `onScroll`.)

Answer (score 6):

If you want detect when user scroll over certain **div**, you can do something like this:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    var distanceScrolled = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    console.log('Scrolled: ' + distanceScrolled);
}
```

For example, if your **div** appear after scroll until the position 112:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    var distanceScrolled = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (distanceScrolled > 112) {
      do something...
    }
}
```

But as you can see you don't need a **div**, just the offset distance you want something to happen.

Answer (score 2):

## Use an interval to check

You can setup an interval to keep checking if the user has scrolled then do something accordingly.

Borrowing from the great [John Resig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Resig) in [his article](https://johnresig.com/blog/learning-from-twitter/).

Example:

```
    let didScroll = false;

    window.onscroll = () => didScroll = true;

    setInterval(() => {
        if ( didScroll ) {
            didScroll = false;
            console.log('Someone scrolled me!')
        }
    }, 250);
```

[See live example](https://jsbin.com/qohamuguru/edit?console,output)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, btw here we checking the function every 250ms right? Won't this increase the load on the website?

Comment: @Nivethan As long as the `didScroll` is false there won't be any effect on performance.
If you want to free up memory you can clear the interval when you don't require it anymore using `clearInterval()`

Answer (score -1):

their are 2 events for that

```
const elm = document.querySelector("urElement");
elm.onscroll = () => // ...
elm.onwheel = () => // ...
```

I perfer to use onwheel since it gives you more infos like the direction
they're scrolling with the wheelDeltaY/wheelDeltaX property and the speed
with also wheelDeltaY/wheelDeltaX

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is how to detect if the user is scrolling. And in actuality, as [MDN notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event) `wheel` is implementation-dependent and may not fire when the user scrolls (e.g., when using arrow keys or PgUp or PgDwn keys).