# How to show or hide a menu when I scroll down or up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]
When I am scrolling down to hide this menu and when I am scrolling up to show this.

My menu bot is:

```
<script>
            var previousScroll = 0;
            $(window).scroll(function(event){
               var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
               if (scroll > previousScroll){
                   $("menu-footer").filter(':not(:animated)').slideUp();
               } else {
                  $("menu-footer").filter(':not(:animated)').slideDown();
               }
               previousScroll = scroll;
            });
    </script>

    <section id="menu-footer">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <li><a href="javascript:history.back()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i><?php _e("Back", ET_DOMAIN); ?></a></li>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="<?php echo $nearby_active; ?>" href="#" id="search-nearby"><i class="fa fa-compass"></i><?php _e("Nearby", ET_DOMAIN); ?></a>
                <form id="nearby" action="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link('place')  ?>" method="get" >
                    <input type="hidden" name="center" id="center_nearby" />
                </form>
            </li>
            <!--<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Submit</a></li>-->
            <!--<li>
                <a class="<?php echo $review_active; ?>" href="<?php echo et_get_page_link('list-reviews') ?>">
                    <i class="fa fa-comment"></i><?php _e("Reviews", ET_DOMAIN); ?>
                </a>
            </li>-->
            <li><a class="<?php echo $post-place; ?>" href="<?php echo et_get_page_link('post-place')?>"><i class="fa fa-flag-checkered"></i><?php _e("Post an Ad", ET_DOMAIN); ?></a></li>
            <?php if(has_nav_menu('et_mobile_header')) { ?>
            <li>
                <li><a href="#" class="search-btn"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i><?php _e("Search", ET_DOMAIN); ?></a></li>
            </li>       
            <li>                
                <a href="javascript:history.back()"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i><?php _e("Refresh", ET_DOMAIN); ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

The script above is what I try to use for hiding my menu.
My CSS for menu-footer is:

```
#menu-footer {
    width: 100%;
    background: #5f6f81;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 100
}
```

What am I missing to make this script working? If you have another solution for me it will be helpful.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I made this first example in plain Javascript to let it easy to understand with a quick look in the code. It hides the menu changing the 'bottom' attribute of the CSS style (from 0 to -100) according to the scrollbar's position (when the scrollbar is more than 0 pixels from the top). The menu shows up again (from -100 to 0) if the scrollbar comes back to the top (0px). A CSS transition effect animates the change:

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", bringmenu);

function bringmenu() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
        document.getElementById("bottommenu").style.bottom = "-100%";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("bottommenu").style.bottom = "0";
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: lavender;
}

#bottommenu {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: tomato;  
  -webkit-transition: bottom 2s;
  transition: bottom 2s;
}
```

```html
<div id=content>
<p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p>
</div>

<div id=bottommenu>
<span>bottom </span><span>bottom </span><span>bottom </span><span>bottom </span><br><span>bottom </span><span>bottom </span><span>bottom </span><span>bottom </span>
</div>
```

**Update:** As requested on the comments, this second snippet brings/hides the menu when scrolling up/down, regardless of the bar's current position (to find the direction, when the scroll is activated it compares the current position with the previous position then stores the current position in a variable to be compared in the next scroll event):

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){  
   var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;  
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       document.getElementById("bottommenu").style.bottom = "-100%";
   } else {
      document.getElementById("bottommenu").style.bottom = "0";
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: honeydew;
}

#bottommenu {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: hotpink;  
  -webkit-transition: bottom 2s;
  transition: bottom 2s;
}
```

```html
<div id=content>
<p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p>
</div>

<div id=bottommenu>
<span>bottom </span><span>bottom </span><span>bottom </span><span>bottom </span><br><span>bottom </span><span>bottom </span><span>bottom </span><span>bottom </span>
</div>
```

> [scroll direction code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31223774/5875416) by [@Prateek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1912583/prateek)

Comment: Is perfect, work, but is one problem when i scrolling up i want to display my menu-footer immediate, not when i have scrollTop = 0. Thanks

Comment: this worked great for me, how would i do it so it doesnt do it as soon as you scroll... say like after 20px has been scrolled?

Comment: @SamJones put `20` instead of `0` in this line: `if (document.body.scrollTop > 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0)` the result will be `if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20)`

Answer (score 5):

Basically you need to get this using 3 main ideas.

1. Set menu/header to fixed.
2. When scrolling down, add a class to remove the header/menu.
3. When scrolling up, remove the class that hides the header/menu.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/s6mLJ/31/)  from Marius Craciunoiu

Html:

```
<header class="nav-down">
    This is your menu.
</header>
<main>
    This is your body.
</main>
<footer>
    This is your footer.
</footer>
```

Javascript:

```
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

CSS:

```
   body {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

header {
    background: #f5b335;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-up {
    top: -40px;
}

main {
   background:url(
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAPklEQVQYV2O8dOnSfwYg0NPTYwTRuAAj0QqxmYBNM1briFaIzRbi3UiRZ75uNgUHGbfvabgfsHqGaIXYPAMAD8wgC/DOrZ4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=
   ) repeat;
    height: 2000px;
}

footer { background: #ddd;}
* { color: transparent}
```