# Scroll to top of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I'm trying to create something like http://deathtrap.co/ - where when you scroll you automatically go to the top of the next or previous div

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#scroll-over').position().top}, 'slow');

});
```

This works to scroll to the next div but then you can't scroll back up. 
I just have the two sections I want to scroll between.

```
<div id = "banner">
   content
</div>
<div id ="scroll-over">
  content
</div>
```

Comment: I think youll have to check the scroll direction to know to scroll up or down.  Check this post out. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31223774/3366016

Answer (score 1):

Do the follwoing in jQuery:

Firstly you set the current div to 1 because the website starts at the top. 
Then you can see that I implemented a function which indicates whether the user scrolls up or down. If he scrolls down you set the current div to 2. And jQuery will scroll down to that div. Remember that you have to give the right ID's.

```
var currentDiv = 1;

var mousewheelevt = (/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel" //FF doesn't recognize mousewheel as of FF3.x
$('html, body').bind(mousewheelevt, function(e){

    var evt = window.event || e //equalize event object     
    evt = evt.originalEvent ? evt.originalEvent : evt; //convert to originalEvent if possible               
    var delta = evt.detail ? evt.detail*(-40) : evt.wheelDelta //check for detail first, because it is used by Opera and FF

    if(delta > 0) {
        //scroll up
        currentDiv = 1;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#"+currentDiv).offset().top
        }, 500);
    }
    else{
        //scroll down
        currentDiv = 2;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#"+currentDiv).offset().top
        }, 500);
    }   

});
```

Lets say your html looks like this:

```
<div id = "1">
   content
</div>
<div id ="2">
  content
</div>
```

If you give them a height of 100% you can scroll between them. I will ad an live example later.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems to be a bit glitchy though. If you could add an example that would be great!