# Capture Scroll Event on Element with overflow: hidden Using Javascript

Tags: javascript

**EDIT:** Thanks for the comments so far! Here's a JS fiddle with (hopefully all of) the relevant code:

https://jsfiddle.net/3y1cw6nt/

I have an image slider set up where the images' classes are toggled between `.above`, `.active` and `.below`, and their `top:` attribute changes accordingly.

At the moment the toggle is activated by an event listener for up and down arrow key presses, and I have `html, body { height: 100vh, overflow: hidden }` so that the user can't scroll to the the images which are `.below` or `.above`.

Is there a way to still capture scroll up and down events and trigger the class changes using Javascript?

I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223341/javascript-detecting-scroll-direction), but it isn't working - `var st` is undefined no matter what I do to the page, which I guess is because no scroll event is being captured and therefore `var st` is never declared.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: please post your code...

Comment: Add an event that is a bit higher than the page, with no content and as overlay.when someone scrolls you can detect it with that element

Answer (score 0):

The body doesn't scroll, so there is no scroll event.

Have a look at a different set of events: [`mousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove), [`touch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent). Support for touch events can be rather varied across devices, so perhaps a library like [Hammer](http://hammerjs.github.io/) would also come in handy.