# Is it somehow possible to scroll specific div without mouseenter to it

Tags: javascript, css

I've got a 2 column layout, where left column is fixed and right column is enabled to scroll. I've set `overflow: hidden;` to `body` because I don't want to scroll body. But is it somehow possible to scroll my second column with text without directly moving cursor to it (scroll it globally by mousewhell)? Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ketysek/4ysm4h0f/

Comment: Is the left column ever going to have enough content to require scrolling? What about mobile support?

Comment: Content in left column doesn't require scrolling :) On mobiles there's no 2 columns (left is on the top), so scrolling on body is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind an `onwheel` event to the left column and scroll the right column instead. Check the [updated fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/4ysm4h0f/2/)

```
document.getElementsByClassName('left')[0].onwheel = function(event) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('right')[0].scrollTop += 10 * event.deltaY;
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I need :)

Answer (score 2):

@Fission answer is correct.

This answer is for old browsers support.

```
if (document.body.addEventListener) {
    document.body.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
    document.body.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", 
                                    MouseWheelHandler, false);
}

else document.body.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler);

function MouseWheelHandler(e) {
    var right= document.getElementsByClassName("right")[0];
    var e = window.event || e; // old IE support
    right.scrollTop += e.deltaY * 5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

basically i think you cant do this thing smoothly, but if i try to be creative you can assign "wheel" event to the body of the page , and add anchor inside your text you want to be scrolled, and inside the function that take care of the wheel event move to that anchor.

to recognized wheel direction read this : [Javascript - Detecting scroll direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223341/javascript-detecting-scroll-direction)