# Host listener for scroll is not working in angular2

Tags: angular, pdf, typescript, scroll

In my pdf viewer i want to perform some action on scroll event so I have used @hostlistener but its not working.So please tell how can I integrate this scroll event with this pdf viewer component.

```
import { Component,HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'example-app',
  template: `
  <div (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
  <div>
      <label>PDF src</label>  
  </div>
  <div>
      <label>Page:</label>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Page" [(ngModel)]="page" >
  </div>
 <div>
  <pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc" 
              [page]="page" 
              [original-size]="true" 
              style="display: block;"
    (after-load-complete)="callBackFn($event)"  (scroll)="onScroll($event)"></pdf-viewer>
    </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyPDFViewerComponent {
  pdfSrc: string = '/pdf-test.pdf';
  page: number = 1;
   @HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
    onScroll(event) { 
       alert("scrolling");
   }

  callBackFn(pdf: PDFDocumentProxy) {
   // do anything with "pdf"
   alert("loade");
    console.log("pdf",pdf);
}
}
```

I have tried to put (scroll)="onScroll($event)" on two places for testing but its neither working any where nor any error displays in console.

Note : pdf-viewer is third party library that I have used for displaying pdf.

Comment: Hard to tell from your code. Perhaps you want `(window:scroll)`. Otherwise please provide a Plunker that allows to investigate.

Comment: How can I implement (window:scroll)??

Comment: As I mentioned above, it's unclear what the problem is exactly. ` `@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])` listens to whole page scrolls. It's just a guess that this is what you want.

Comment: How can I get direction of scroll as upward or downward??

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/KIxLAcQFooT0RUap2Qn6?p=preview working fine without `pdf-viewer` as i don't know how to implement it.

Comment: I have implemented it but How can I get direction of scroll as upward or downward??

Comment: I wonder if we can get direction !!!! Why do you need it any specific reason. scrolling event works for up n down direction

Comment: In my pdf viewer I want to implement functionality on scroll up and down event like render increasing and decreasing page .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223341/javascript-detecting-scroll-direction