# Javascript: Is it possible to delay a scroll event when scrolling up only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, delay

I am triggering a click event on scroll in order to collapse and expand a header menu at the top of my page. I have added throttling to my js in order to remove a glitch that was being caused by excess events firing.

**Here is my current JS:**

```
<script>
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
   var hT = jQuery('.closemenu').offset().top,
       hH = jQuery('.closemenu').outerHeight(),
       wH = jQuery(window).height(),
       wS = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
    console.log((hT-wH) , wS);
   if (wS > (hT+hH-wH) && (hT > wS) && (wS+wH > hT+hH)){
   jQuery('.menu-bar').trigger('click');
   }

function throttle(fn, threshhold, scope) {
  threshhold || (threshhold = 1250);
  var last,
      deferTimer;
  return function () {
    var context = scope || this;

    var now = +new Date,
        args = arguments;
    if (last && now < last + threshhold) {
      // hold on to it
      clearTimeout(deferTimer);
      deferTimer = setTimeout(function () {
        last = now;
        fn.apply(context, args);
      }, threshhold);
    } else {
      last = now;
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }
  };
}

});
</script>
```

Now I've realised that I need to add another parameter in order to delay the event from firing by 1000ms but **only on scroll up**. This is because the header menu container hasn't expanded when the event fires so there is a glitch that exists on scroll up only.

Can anyone recommend the correct function to capture only scroll up actions and apply a delay of 1000ms before the event (`jQuery('.menu-bar').trigger('click');`) fires?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223341/detecting-scroll-direction

Comment: @ddinchev thanks for the link! I might be able to make this work :) will post any results