# Javascript On Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make it so that when I scroll my page up or down it runs a different corresponding function. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223341/detecting-scroll-direction) but I have tried their answers and have had no luck. 
 NOTE: This page does not have a normally appearing scrollbar. There is nowhere to scroll to.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>This is an example of the type of page I am talking about. It has a full page &lt;body&gt; which is what I have been trying to add the onscroll function to. I am open to other solutions though.
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  if (e.deltaY < 0) {
    console.log('scrolling up');
  }
  if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    console.log('scrolling down');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>This is an example of the type of page I am talking about. It has a full page &lt;body&gt; which is what I have been trying to add the onscroll function to. I am open to other solutions though.
</body>
```

Comment: No luck. The page I am trying to do this with does not have anywhere to scroll to.