# How to achieve negative scrolling in Javascript/Typescript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I have a div element to which I can drag with my mouse pointer. When I touch or cross the right or bottom boundary it automatically displays the scrollers. However when I touch or cross the div element through the top or left side boundary there are no scrollers.

Is it possible to get scrollers for the left and top side also if my div crosses these boundaries(top and left)?

Here is the code I did for dragging:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
 
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1>Draggable DIV Element</h1>

<p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the DIV element</p>

<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p>
  <p>this</p>
  <p>DIV</p>
</div>

<script>
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can say you can't do this since browsers do not allow negative scrolling.

What you can do, however, is to recalculate the position of all the other elements and scroll the document so that it creates an illusion of adding the negative scroll. If you move one element from 10px to -20px left you have to now put it on 0 and add 30 to every other element. You can then use window.scrollTo() function to shift the visible area 30 pixels right as well. Just make sure you do that recalculation on drag end. You do not want to recalculate it every time you drag an item on the screen.