# Vue @scroll on vertical only

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom-events

Been searching and wasn't able to find the right solution for me. What I wanted to achieve is to trigger the **@scroll** functionality if and only the scroll is at the **bottom of the element** and when it's **scrolled vertically only**. This is the HTML:

```
<table @scroll="loadMoreData">
...
</table>
```

This is the Vue functionality:

```
loadMoreData({ target: { scrollTop, clientHeight, scrollHeight }}) {
     if (scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight) {
         // load more data here...
     }
},
```

This is working fine but the problem with this is it also **triggers when scrolled horizontally**. How to trigger this when **scrolled vertically only**? Thanks.

Comment: I doubt this is possible, seeing as the underlying javascript event doesn't differentiate between horizontal and vertical scrolling. However, you can keep track of the vertical/horizontal position yourself to detect a horizontal scroll.

Comment: @Stanislas thanks for answering. What's the best way to track of the vertical position only?

Comment: Cache the values of `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` and compare their value against current ones in the scroll handler. If `scrollTop` has changed but `scrollLeft` haven’t then you know it’s a purely vertical scroll.

Comment: I would take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31223774/6822962