# onScroll isn't firing any action (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying (and failing) to use "onScroll" on a div. All others commands are working properly. I already tried use only the onScroll and gave me nothing too. Why it isn't working?

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div onClick="printSC()" onPointerMove="printPM()" onWheel="printWR()" onScroll="printSR()" style="height: 5000px">
        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
        function printSC() {
            console.log("click");
        }
        function printPM() {
            console.log("moved");
        }
        function printWR() {
            console.log("roll");
        }
        function printSR() {
            console.log("scroll");
        }
    </script>

</html>
```

I added a second code to show the "onClick" working properly on "body", but I neet it in a "div".

Code 2:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Test</title>

</head>
 <body onScroll="printSR()">
  <div style="height: 5000px" ></div>
    
  <script>
      function printSR() {
          console.log("scroll");
      }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `<div>` height is not 100%, you can use the `wheel` event instead of the scroll event. Currently, the `onScroll` event is not fired because the `height` style of the `<div>` element is not set. The `height` style is not applied when the `<div>` element's `display` property is `inline`. There are two ways to solve this problem.

###### Method-1

Similar to the `scroll` event, the `wheel` event can be used if the `height` of the `<div>` element does not exceed `100%`:

```js
function printSR() {
  console.log("scroll");
}

let onwheelContainer = document.getElementById('onwheelContainer');
onwheelContainer.addEventListener('wheel', printSR);
```

```css
#onwheelContainer {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="onwheelContainer"></div>
```

###### Method-2

Applying a `height` style after applying the `block` style to the `<div>` element's `display` property:

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  height: 5000px;
}
```

###### Method-3

Applying the `height` style to the `<div>` element using `!important`:

```css
.container {
  height: 5000px !important;
}
```

Additionally, the `<script></script>` element must be written before the closing `</body>` tag. In the following application, the class style `.container` has been applied to the `<div>` element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Test</title>

  <style>
    /* [METHOD-1] The class style applied to the <div> element. */
    .container{
      display: block;
      height: 5000px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    
    /* [METHOD-2] Class style that can be applied to the <div> element. */
    .container2{
      height: 5000px !important;
    }
    
    #onwheelContainer {
      display: block;
      height: 50px;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- The class style ".container" has been applied to the <div> element. -->
  <div class="container" onClick="printSC()" onPointerMove="printPM()" onWheel="printWR()" onScroll="printSR()"></div>
  
  <div id="onwheelContainer"></div>
    
  <!-- The <script></script> element is positioned before the closing tag </body>. -->
  <script>
      function printSC() {
          console.log("click");
      }
      function printPM() {
          console.log("moved");
      }
      function printWR() {
          console.log("roll");
      }
      function printSR() {
          console.log("scroll");
      }
      
      /* Similar to the scroll event, the wheel event can be used if the height of the <div> element does not exceed 100%. */
      let onwheelContainer = document.getElementById('onwheelContainer');
      
      onwheelContainer.addEventListener('wheel', printSR);
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Sadly, it still not working for me. I tried to put the event on the body and worked, but I need it in a div.

Comment: The answer is simple; you cannot trigger the `onScroll` event on any `<div>` if the `height` of a page does not exceed `100%`!

Comment: Even if the height of the <div> is not more than 100% then the onScroll event on the <div> will not fire.

Comment: @Felipe I updated my answer. If the `<div>` height is not more than 100%, the `wheel` event can be used for the same function; I added this property to **Method-1**.

Comment: Again, thanks for reply. If I understood correctly, the wheel event will replace the "oneWheel", not the "onScroll". The onWheel was OK, but it's fired only when the mouse wheel is used. I need to get all commands that the user uses to scroll page down (wheel, scroll the sidebar, page down, etc).

Comment: The scroll event of the page you are talking about. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45719399/15032688)

Comment: Now you nailed it! Absolutely awesome. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. `:)`

Comment: You're talking about height, but what about horizontal scrolling?