# Navigate to the next/previous anchor point onScroll with JS

Tags: javascript, nav, onscroll

On my page, I have navigation that scroll to anchor points on click. But I want to go up and down to these anchors on Scroll (depend on the direction of scrolling).
Code is my navigation:

```
<div id="top-menu" class="verticalNav textCenter">

<ul class="bg-dark-transparent">
  <li><a id="scroll1" class="liColor noTextDecoration sideMenu" href="#introduction">Intro</a></li>

  <li><a id="scroll2" class="liColor noTextDecoration sideMenu" href="#overview">Overview</a></li>

  <li><a id="scroll3" class="liColor noTextDecoration sideMenu" href="#process">Process</a></li>

  <li><a id="scroll4" class="liColor noTextDecoration sideMenu" href="#research">Research</a></li>

  <li><a id="scroll5" class="liColor noTextDecoration sideMenu" href="#analysis">Analysis</a></li>

  <li><a id="scroll6" class="liColor noTextDecoration sideMenu" href="#ideation">Ideation</a></li>

  <li><a id="scroll7" class="liColor noTextDecoration sideMenu" href="#prototype">Prototype</a></li>

  <li><a id="scroll8" class="liColor noTextDecoration sideMenu" href="#testing">Testing</a></li>

  <li><a id="scroll9" class="liColor noTextDecoration sideMenu" href="#result">Result</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post of an example of what you have tried to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223341/detecting-scroll-direction)

Then inside of the if checks you would jump to the anchors using `window.location.href = ‘webpage\#anchor’;`

You will probably want to store the names of you anchors in an array or object to loop through and keep track of the current anchor.

If you need help with that as well I can help also. If this is a solution for your problem!

Comment: Yes, please! I think it should work for me.

Comment: I don’t your full experience with javascript is, but the least complicated route would be to manual create an array

`const anchorArray = [‘#anchor1’];`

`let currentAnchor = -1;`

During your scroll event either increment or decrement your scroll index to keep track of which anchor is next
Then  your jump to anchor would look like


`window.location.href = \`www.website.com/${anchorArray[currentAnchor]}\`;`

Comment: Better yet here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/justbarnt/pen/xxWrpvv?editors=1010)