# javascript to be activate on page scroll

Tags: javascript, html

i've got some code from codepen where a progress bar fills up depending on a given number out of 100. i want it to activate when it is scrolled to, instead of on reload, which it currently is set to. I cant find anything on here already.
Javascript is new to me, so trying to get the hang of it, thanks

```js
$('.progress-wrap').each(function(){
    percent = $(this);
    bar = $(this).children('.progress-bar');
    moveProgressBar(percent, bar);
});

  // on browser resize...
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('.progress-wrap').each(function(){
        percent = $(this);
        bar = $(this).children('.progress-bar');
        moveProgressBar(percent, bar);
    });
  });

  // SIGNATURE PROGRESS
  function moveProgressBar(percent, bar) {
      var getPercent = (percent.data('progress-percent') / 100);
      var getProgressWrapWidth = percent.width();
      var progressTotal = getPercent * getProgressWrapWidth;
      var animationLength = 1000;

      // on page load, animate percentage bar to data percentage length
      // .stop() used to prevent animation queueing
      bar.stop().animate({
          left: progressTotal
      }, animationLength);
  }
```

```html
<div class="progress-wrap progress star" data-progress-percent="70">
   <div class="progress-bar progress"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Similar to how you do `$(window).resize(function() { ... }`, you can wrap whatever you want to happen on scroll with `$(window).scroll(function() { ... }`

Comment: thanks that works. but i may have phrased my question wrong, i want the javascript to be activated when it is scrolled to, not just when i scroll, as the feature is far down the page, so if im at the top, by the time ive scrolled to the feature, it has already activated. @tylerRoper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

Replace `#someElement` with the Id of the element that when in view fires the function you want.

`someFunction()` is the function that you want to run when the element is in view

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() >= $('#someElement').position().top ) {
        someFunction();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using jquery - it would be easier to do this in vanilla javascript like so:

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {  
// called when the window is scrolled.  
}
```

You may want to have a look at: [Detect if user is scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605197/detect-if-user-is-scrolling) for jquery options.

Comment: Personally I don't see this as any "easier", not to mention it's a pretty bad code smell when you start mixing jQuery and vanilla JS for things like event handling.

Comment: Hence the reason why I pointed the user towards the jQuery option from another SO question. It is easier in my opinion - thought including the link might put the user on a learning journey. Agree - not a good idea to mix vanilla and jQuery.