# How to allow the user to scroll when they are continuously pulled down as new data arrives?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create something like a chat where the scroll automatically pulls down when the user receives new messages. However, I am facing a problem when the user tries to scroll up. When I am scrolling up and receive a new message, my scroll always pulls down.

Here is a sample of code: [link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/scrolltobottomexample-f90lz?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js)

Could someone explain or provide a code example on how to address this issue?

Comment: is your question answered? It would be great if you give feedback if people take effort and try to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the user is currently scrolling. The question [Detect if user is scrolling (Stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605197/detect-if-user-is-scrolling) handles this fundamental question.

There are multiple ways of implementing what you need. Choose what fits best to you and provide a variable that represents your scrolling state. Then you can check for it before calling `scrollIntoView`

```
if (!userIsScrolling)
    messagesEndRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}
```